Letting the athlete's mind do the workout for you
I remember seeing one scene from a movie, I would assume it played sometime in the 90s or early 2000s. In this movie they had a technology that allowed people to switch their bodies.
Here's the scene I remember: One of the movies character's walks into an office, expecting to see a company executive, or his boss or so. But there ends up an athletic looking guy sitting at the desk instead. The athletic looking guy explains that he has hired someone to do a strenuous workout for him. Then we see in a corner of the office the actual company executive working out on a treadmill. And I think they were even still wearing their regular clothes, meaning the executive who was working out was in suit and tie, while the "personal trainer" was wearing a sleeveless shirt.
I kind of remember seeing a MRT-scanner like looking thing, that allowed them to switch their minds and bodies.
I don't know if this would be a action/thriller or a comedy, but it seemed more like a thriller, starring someone like Bruce Willis or Keanu Reeves.
But I was quite little when I saw this scene, so I don't know how much my mind if filling in and how much is actual memory.
Lately though I have wondered more and more about this mysterious movie and kinda would like to see it! :D

You're looking for Xchange from 2001 with Stephen Baldwin and Kyle MacLachlan.

In the near future, a company called Xchange owns a mind transference technology that enables instantaneous travel by swapping bodies with someone at the destination. A member of the privileged corporate class ("Corpie") Xchanging for the first time unwittingly switches bodies with a terrorist. Forced to hide in a limited life span cloned body with just 2 days remaining, he races against time to stop the terrorist and regain his body.

The trailer actually starts with the exact scene you're describing:




Thanks!  :) I suppose I must have seen the trailer for it...
